# Unable to create a color for the nodes by running the labelPropogation query

Tags: neo4j, vis.js

To get a cluster of nodes with same color, we need to run this query:

```
 CALL algo.labelPropagation('cabinet_2','Parameter','privileges_2', 
{  write:true,   
 partitionProperty:'community', weightProperty:'count'})
```

I also ran this:

```
CALL algo.labelPropagation(null,null,'OUTGOING',{write:true, 
partitionProperty:'partition',   
   weightProperty:'count'})
```

Now, despite running this query, there is no difference in the nodes:

[image]

I want uniform color as shown in here:

[image]

Also, do i have to run Call algo .labelPropogation query for all the nodes ?

```
 var cypherQuery = "MATCH (n)-[r]->(m) RETURN n,r,m;";

     var config = {
         container_id: "viz",
         server_url: "bolt://localhost:11001/",
         server_user: "neo4j",
         server_password: "Virtuallib1",
         labels: {

             "ngoconnectionserviceimplhttpsoap11endpoint": {
                "thickness": "weight",
                "caption": true,
               "community": "partition",
                "sizeCypher": "MATCH (n) WHERE id(n) = {id} MATCH (n)-[r]-() RETURN sum(r.weight) AS c"
            },
            "ngoconnectionserviceimplhttpsoap12endpoint": {
               "thickness": "weight",
               "caption": true,
               "community": "partition",
               "sizeCypher": "MATCH (n) WHERE id(n) = {id} MATCH (n)-[r]-() RETURN sum(r.weight) AS c"
           },
           "connparams_2": {
            "thickness": "weight",
            "caption": true,
           "community": "partition",
            "sizeCypher": "MATCH (n) WHERE id(n) = {id} MATCH (n)-[r]-() RETURN sum(r.weight) AS c"
        },

        "connparams": {
            "thickness": "weight",
            "caption": true,
           "community": "partition",
            "sizeCypher": "MATCH (n) WHERE id(n) = {id} MATCH (n)-[r]-() RETURN sum(r.weight) AS c"
        },            

           "System": {
               "thickness": "weight",
               "caption": true,
               "community": "partition"
           },

         },
         relationships: {
             "Parameter": {
                 "thickness": "weight",
                 "caption": true,
                 "community": "partition",
                 "color":'red'
             },
             "Method": {
                "thickness": "weight",
                "caption": true,
                "community": "Blue",

            },

            "System": {
                "thickness": "weight",
                "caption": true,
                "community": "partition",

            },
         },

         cluster_labels: {
            "Parameter": "partition"
          },

         initial_cypher:cypherQuery ,        
        arrows: true,
        hierarchical_layout:true,
        hierarchical_sort_method:"directed",

     };
```

Comment: Currently not possible with neovis. Only selected config fields from vis.js are included in neovis. There is an issue open - https://github.com/neo4j-contrib/neovis.js/issues/36

Comment: Hey you found any solution for this ? @techdive